# What can I use to repair a crack in the plastic layer of a bathtub?

Tags: bathtub

I have a bathtub with a plastic (I think) surface layer which has a small crack in it. The crack is at the bottom, on the inside. Some sort of rusty liquid has now started to ooze out from the crack, which feels less than hygienic.

Before I replace the whole bathtub, I'd like to try to repair the crack. What approach would be the best here? What sealant would be recommended? It obviously needs to be both water-resistant and non-toxic.

I'm thankful for any advice!

[image: crack in plastic surface layer of bathtub]

Comment: Strong Opinion: I'd replace the tub. This question has been asked and answered before and numerous people have gone down the path you desire, its generally a waste of time to do so.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-is-the-best-way-to-repair-a-cracked-bathtub?rq=1

Comment: I live near surfers. I got one to repair my fiberglass tub.

Comment: You could call some plumbers to see if they know of tub repairmen.