# How to fix bathtub blemishes?

Tags: repair, bathtub

How can I take care of this bathtub blemish? It is as if a small part is missing, less than an inch in size. Also, I have a couple scratches that I'd like to hide, but I wasn't able to get a focused picture on them. Thanks, 
[image: bathtub blemish]

Comment: Looks like a fiberglass tub - is that right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to repair a cracked bathtub?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-is-the-best-way-to-repair-a-cracked-bathtub)

Comment: I think it’s hard to tell if acrylic shell or gellcoat both have chopped fiberglass sprayed form. I would go with acrylic. 2 part epoxy sanded down with a smiling sticker to hide it.

Comment: I don't know if it is fiberglass. I know it seems a bit hollow to the hit. I tried to discover this with Google searching.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound crazy but what I have been seeing used in a residential and commercial setting of remodeling, is Bondo.

I have seen it come with some really great results.

I have seen it used on everything from wood to metals.

Simply apply it, Let it dry and sand it smooth.